# Sum of closed ideals is closed in a $C^{\ast}$-algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, ideals, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^{\ast}$-algebra. Let $I_1$ and $I_2$ be closed ideals in $A$, then it is known that $I_1+I_2$ is closed in $A$. This motivated me to ask the following:

> Let $\{I_{\alpha}\}_ {\alpha \in I}$ be a collection of closed ideals in $A$, then is it true that $\sum_{\alpha \in I} I_{\alpha}= \{ \sum_ { \alpha \in I'} x_{\alpha}, x_\alpha \in I_{\alpha} , I' \subseteq I, I'\hspace{0.1mm}  \text{is finite}\}$ is closed in $A$.

Any references?

Comment: What do you mean by an infinite sum of ideals in this context?

Comment: @alepopoulo110: Edited, thank you!

Comment: It might be better to call your indexing set something other than $I$ (maybe something like $\mathscr{A}$?) to avoid confusion, since $I$ and $I_\alpha$ are different types of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a thing already fails for families of subspaces (you always need to take the closure). In any case, here is a specific example in your situation.

Let $A=\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$, $I=\mathbb N$, $I_\alpha=\mathbb C\,e_n$. Then what you called $\sum_\alpha I_\alpha$ is $c_{00}$, the set of functions that are eventually zero. The closure of $c_{00}$ is $c_0$